# Database connection fail when trying to connect database at google app engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

Database connection fail when trying to connect database at google app engine

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$con = mysql_connect('<host>','<username>','<password>') or die(mysql_error());
```

I got error message.

> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname
>   failed. errno=0 in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~testappgraymatics/1.388814076593258081/helloworld.php
>   on line 7 Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses:
>   gethostbyname failed. errno=0 in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~testappgraymatics/1.388814076593258081/helloworld.php
>   on line 7 php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0

Comment: you won't be able to connect to non-cloud-SQL databases on GAE. Are you?

Comment: I want to connect mysql  not cloud-SQL , is it possible ??

Comment: no, it's not possible.

Comment: It is possible if you use sockets, which requires billing enabled.